# Debian 11 setting DHCP for 2 or more client networks

Tags: dhcp

I have 2 bridges (vmbr1 vmbr2) on proxmox server.

vmbr1 IP: 192.168.106.1 for NAT clients

vmbr2 IP: 192.168.107.1 for Local only

I have set up DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server) and it works perfectly with one network segment (on vmbr1).

When I attempt to set the second segment (vmbr2), DHCP server fails with the message:

```
No subnet declaration for vmbr2 (no IPv4 addresses).
** Ignoring requests on vmbr2.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface vmbr2 is attached. **
```

for this error this statement apparently should fix the issue:

```
subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
```

However then the error becomes this:

```
 isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
 isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
 Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
 bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
 before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
 process and the information we find helpful for debugging.

 exiting.
```

Here is the working  /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
INTERFACESv4="vmbr1"
#INTERFACESv4="vmbr1 vmbr2"
#INTERFACESv6=""
```

Here is the working /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

```
option domain-name "mydomain.ca";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
  
subnet 192.168.106.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.106.20 192.168.106.150;
#subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 192.168.106.1;
}

#subnet 192.168.107.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#range 192.168.107.20 192.168.107.150;
#subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#option routers 192.168.107.1;
#}
```

The options causing issue are commented out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not asking you to add a line

```
subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
```

There is no such directive as `subnet-mask`. What you were thinking was probably `option subnet-mask`; however, it's not required because the mask is already specified in the subnet declaration (i.e. the `subnet x.x.x.x netmask y.y.y.y { ... }` block).

The `No subnet declaration for vmbr2` means that `dhcpd` wants to see a `subnet ... { ... }` block with a network address and mask that match the settings `vmbr2` is currently configured to.

Here's a corrected version of your working `dhcpd.conf` ready to serve two subnets:

```
option domain-name "mydomain.ca";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;
  
subnet 192.168.106.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { # <-- subnet mask already specified here
range 192.168.106.20 192.168.106.150;
##subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;  <--- this line should be deleted
option routers 192.168.106.1;
}

subnet 192.168.107.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 { # <-- subnet mask already specified here
range 192.168.107.20 192.168.107.150;
##subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;  <--- this line should be deleted
option routers 192.168.107.1;
}
```

You are apparently viewing the error messages through the `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service` output. You should be aware that it shows only the last 10 lines of the actual output. A much better way to verify the correct syntax of your DHCP server configuration would be to use the `-t` option of `dhcpd`.

When I saved your original "working /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf" as `/tmp/dhcpd.conf.test`, uncommented the first `subnet-mask` line and ran `dhcpd -cf /tmp/dhcpd.conf.test -t`, here is the full output:

```
# dhcpd -cf /tmp/dhcpd.conf.test -t
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
/tmp/dhcpd.conf.test line 6: semicolon expected.
subnet-mask 255.
             ^
Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging.

exiting.
```

Note that the verbiage at the end probably caused you to miss the important part:

```
/tmp/dhcpd.conf.test line 6: semicolon expected.
subnet-mask 255.
             ^
Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
```

indicating that the `subnet-mask` should not be used like that.

Comment: The "working" version that you suggested was the first I tried, however id did not work, providing me with the first error. Later on I looked up for the solution.

Comment: Interestingly, after removing all extra lines when I run " dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -t " or "dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -t vmbr1 vmbr2", no errors are shown. But If I do "service isc-dhcp-server restart", the "service isc-dhcp-server status" does show the error                                        \

Comment: Then you'll need to run `journalctl -xeu isc-dhcp-server.service` to view the complete journal of that service, and if necessary, use the up-arrow key to scroll back to see if there is more than one error involved. Sometimes when an error is detected while parsing a configuration file, it throws off the parser and may cause spurious errors afterwards... and if you only check `service isc-dhcp-server status` = `systemctl status isc-dhcp-server`, you may not see **all** the messages produced by the service.